# Set color of points with -inf using scatter

Tags: matplotlib

I'm drawing a scatter plot in which I'm specifying the color of each point:

```
ax.scatter(x, y, c=z)
```

The problem is that some values of `z` are `-inf`, and these points simply aren't plotted. I'd like to set them to some color. I tried this:

```
cm = mpl.cm.get_cmap()
cm.set_under('k',1.0)
cm.set_bad('purple',1.0)
ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap=cm)
```

but there's still no points shown for the `-inf` values.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easiest to overplot the points at infinity:

```
cm = mpl.cm.get_cmap()
cm.set_under('k',1.0)
cm.set_bad('purple',1.0)
ax.scatter(x, y, c=z)
ax.scatter(x[numpy.isinf(z)], y[numpy.isinf(z)], c='b')
```

If you want to exclude positive infinity, this seems to work:

```
cm = mpl.cm.get_cmap()
cm.set_under('k',1.0)
cm.set_bad('purple',1.0)
ax.scatter(x, y, c=z)
indices = numpy.isinf(z) & (z < 0)
ax.scatter(x[indices], y[indices], c='b')
```

All code untested though.

Comment: I came to workaround too. (but I used `isneginf` and `isposinf`)